# Verification of bitmask consisting of few bytes

Tags: c#, .net, bit-manipulation

I have a byte[] array of 4 bytes. Also there are a corresponding 4 byte bitmasks in form of hex values (like 0x02000000) and I need to verify those masks against my byte[] array. While I'm perfectly understand how should I do it on paper with bitwise operations I not sure how to proceed in C# code. Should I separate each byte in mask and verify it against corresponding byte in the array or is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use `BitArray` to get all the bits from your 4 byte array as an array of `boolean`.  For example,

```
var bits = new BitArray(MyByteArray);
if (bits[7]) {
  // then most significant bit of your first byte is set
}
```

`BitArray` will create an array of bits, starting with you least significant bit in your first byte of your array to the end.

Your example of matching against 0x02000000 would look like this:

```
var controlBits = new BitArray(BitConverter.GetBytes(0x02000000));
// me thinks this sould work too as 0x02000000 is an int32, not a long
// var controlBits = new BitArray(0x02000000);
var mybits = new BitArray(MyByteArray)


for (int bitIndex = 0, bitIndex < bits.Length; bitIndex++) {
   if (controlBits[bitIndex] != mybits[bitIndex]) {
       launchICBM(destination = "not this continent");
   }
}

...
```

As a side note, 0x02000000 in a BitArray would translate to only one set bit at myBits[29] me thinks; where 0x00000001 would be a single bit set at myBits[0].

Answer (score 0):

You want to use bitwise operators for this. I assume you have something like this?

```
byte bitMask1 = 0x00000001;
byte bitMask2 = 0x00000002;
byte bitMask3 = 0x00000004;
byte bitMast4 = 0x00000008;

byte[] testArray = new byte[] { 0x00000003, 0x00000015, 0x0000020, 0x00000002 };
```

You can check a byte value against a bitmask using the & operator:

```
if ((testArray[0] & bitMask1) > 0)
{
    // The bits are set in the value
}
else
{
    // The bits are NOT set in the value
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is what the question asks for. The four bytes in the byte array correspond to the four bytes in the bitmask whereas you are just comparing the masks to single bytes.

Comment: OK I misunderstood the question, sorry.

Comment: Not a problem. Its why I always comment before downvoting. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you'll always be dealing with four bytes or less, another approach (depending on what exactly you need; the post is somewhat vague) is to simply store the four bytes in a uint:

```
uint fourBytes = (bytes[0] << 24) | (bytes[1] << 16) | (bytes[2] << 8) | bytes[3];
```

...and then do whatever operations/comparisons/checks you need using uints.